# GUI rendering of simulation

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, simulation

I am currently working on a simulation of tree search and I am trying to design a gui to display the search tree as it is built. I am using the Observer design pattern but seem to have run into the problem where since the gui is a different thread of execution the search seems to finish off before the gui paints to illustrate the simulation. Is there anyway the 
search and the gui for displaying the search as it evolves can be synchronized so that the gui 
reflects the state of the search when it paints.

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should note humans are slow :) I would say step by step approach fits better, so you will need to provide the following functionality:

1. step forward
2. step backward
3. start/stop execution
4. flexible simulation speed

Let's use some animated image as an example ([source](http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~cfs/472_html/AI_SEARCH/SearchAnimations.html)):

[image]

This example is quite simple, but you may notice the fact you can't control the execution is a little bit annoying. Anyway, in order to provide good visualization you have to start with the processing loop design. It seems to be very simple:

1. update the tree
2. render it
3. wait for some time to let the user notice the difference

Does it look like a simple game loop for you?

[image]

Please also see some details [here](http://entropyinteractive.com/2011/02/game-engine-design-the-game-loop/)

I would suggest the following:

1. Define a model to hold a tree state
2. Implement the logic to update the model(tree) using [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)
3. Implement a command queue and command executor
4. Let the view to receive model updated events

[image]

So, every time user presses Next you will create a command (or several commands) and commit it to the model. After executing all commands model is supposed to refresh the view. User will have enough time to understand the change. Automated mode is also possible (you will generate commands with specified delay)